# UI обновляется через Platform.runLater() в процессе работы, но отображается только конечный результат

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, gui, kotlin

Имеется gui-приложение для проверки занятости доменных имен.
Написано на Kotlin + JavaFX.
Единственное окно выглядит так:

[image: GUI приложения]

Элементы: TextField, ProgressBar, TextArea. 
В TextField вводится запрос формата $имяФайлаСДоменами.доменнаяЗона, например: $file1.com или $my_domains.ru (можно вводить и просто интересующий домен вроде yandex.ru, но с этой функцией проблема не связана).

Есть класс, проверяющий имена доменов, "показывая" пользователю свободные (незарегистрированные):

```
class Operator constructor(private var progressBar : ProgressBar,
                       private var output : TextArea) : Thread()
```

Пока этот Оператор один за другим проверяет домены из списка, необходимо, чтобы в UI отображался прогресс в ProgressBar (колВоПроверенныхДоменов / колВоВсехДоменовВСписке) и каждый домен, признаваемый "свободным" сразу отображался в TextArea (append()).

В цикле по всем доменам списка после проверки каждого домена происходит обновление UI при помощи поочередного вызова двух методов:

```
// отображение текущего прогресса (на 1 домен больше)
private fun progressStepUI() {
    progress += progressStep
    Platform.runLater {
        progressBar.progress = progress
    }
}

// вывод имени свободного домена
private fun printLineUI(line: String) {
    Platform.runLater {
        output.appendText("\n$line")
    }
}
```

Работает приложение верно. Домены проверяются один за другим. Однако в процессе проверки UI обновляться не хочет и обновляется только после завершения работы: сначала UI зависает, а потом сразу отображается конечный результат.

В чем проблема?

Все исходники на Github: https://github.com/lyulenkov/whoiscl-plus

Метод класса, выполняющий проверку доменов по списку:

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
private fun freeDomainsByDictionary(_dictName: String, zone: String)
```

P.S.: будьте готовы к тому, что комментарии в моём коде на "англиськам" могут уничтожить ваше зрение и повредить ваш разум. Над англом я ещё работаю, но суть будет ясна, надеюсь.

P.P.S.: после ввода запроса в текстовое поле необходимо нажать Enter.

Comment: У меня подозрения, что operator.processing(inp.text) не отправляется в ваш демон, а выполняется внутри FX потока, что и приводит к его ожиданию до полного завершения функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Platform.runLater()` не предназначен для продолжительных задач, его стоит использовать только для разового изменения UI. Например, он подойдёт для вызова из потока, который получает текст по ссылке, устанавливает этот текст в поле и завершает работу. Для задач, который требуют периодического взаимодействия потока с UI нужно использовать [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html):

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() {
        static final int max = 1000000;
        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
            updateProgress(i, max);
        }
        return null;
    }
};

ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
new Thread(task).start();
```